# Error while downloading images from Wikipedia via python script

Tags: python, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am trying to download all images of a  particular wikipedia page. Here is the code snippet

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib2
import urlparse
from urllib import urlretrieve

site="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pune"
hdr= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
outpath=""
req = urllib2.Request(site,headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req)
soup =bs(page)
tag_image=soup.findAll("img")
for image in tag_image:
        print "Image: %(src)s" % image
        urlretrieve(image["src"], "/home/mayank/Desktop/test")
```

While after running the program I see error with following stack

```
Image: //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Pune_Montage.JPG/250px-Pune_Montage.JPG
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "download_images.py", line 15, in <module>
    urlretrieve(image["src"], "/home/mayank/Desktop/test")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 93, in urlretrieve
    return _urlopener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 239, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 207, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 460, in open_file
    return self.open_ftp(url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 543, in open_ftp
    ftpwrapper(user, passwd, host, port, dirs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 864, in __init__
    self.init()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 870, in init
    self.ftp.connect(self.host, self.port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ftplib.py", line 132, in connect
    self.sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno ftp error] [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

please help on what is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//` is shorthand for the current protocol. It seems like Wikipedia is using the shorthand, so you have to explicitly specify HTTP instead of FTP (which Python is assuming for some reason):

```
for image in tag_image:
    src = 'http:' + image
```

Comment: Thanks @Blender :This solved my issue

However I would just like to add one thing so that if anyone refers this question he won't be mislead. Appending http and image won;t work as mentioned in the answer. Rather I did this :

urlretrieve('http:'+image["src"], outpath)